# Реализация LoG Filter, проблема с рамкой (контуром) изображения

Tags: c++, изображения, фильтры, обработка

Реализовала LoG - фильтр:

```
void LoGFilt(double *&arr, int w, int h, const int nHood, float sigma){
    double *temp = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*w*h);
    copy(arr, temp, 0, 0, w, h, w, w);

    double weight[nHood][nHood];

    double s2 = sigma*sigma;
    for(int j = -nHood/2; j <= nHood/2; ++j){
        for(int i = -nHood/2; i <= nHood/2; ++i){
            int r2 = i*i+j*j;
            weight[i+nHood/2][j+nHood/2] = -(1.0/(M_PI*s2*s2))*(1.0-r2/(2*s2))*exp(-r2/(2*s2));
        }
    }

    int min = INT_MAX;
    int max = -INT_MAX;
    for (int y = nHood/2; y < h - nHood/2; y++) {
      for (int x = nHood/2; x < w - nHood/2; x++) {
        double pixel_value = 0.0;
        for (int j = - nHood/2; j < nHood/2+1; j++) {
          for (int i = -nHood/2; i < nHood/2+1; i++) {
            pixel_value += weight[j + nHood/2][i + nHood/2] * temp[(y + j)*w + x + i];
          }
        }
        if (pixel_value < min) min = pixel_value;
        if (pixel_value > max) max = pixel_value;
      }
    }

    for (int y = nHood/2; y < h - nHood/2; y++) {
      for (int x = nHood/2; x < w - nHood/2; x++) {
        double pixel_value = 0.0;
        for (int j = - nHood/2; j < nHood/2+1; j++) {
          for (int i = -nHood/2; i < nHood/2+1; i++) {
            pixel_value += weight[j + nHood/2][i + nHood/2] * temp[(y + j)*w + x + i];
          }
        }

        pixel_value = 255 * (pixel_value - min) / (max - min);
        arr[y*w+x] = (unsigned char)pixel_value;
      }
    }

    free(temp);
}
```

Сохраняю результат применения фильтра к изображению, а на выходе какие - то четкая черная граница вокруг изображения, как от нее избавиться? Или ошибка где-то в коде? И еще вопрос: коэффициенты данного фильтра считаю верно, а вот что качается дальнейшего действия, т.е. как применять данную маску к изображения - непонятно.

[image: исходное изображение]
[image: полученное изображение]

Comment: Мне ваш результат напоминает больше инверсию (или приближённое к ней), т.к. то что было белым - стало чёрным, и так по всей картинке. Я не в курсе что есть log-фильтр. Добавтье описание.

Comment: @nick_n_a вот здесь хорошо написано об этом фильтре http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm

Comment: @nick_n_a и вправду напоминает инверсию, значит точно идея LoG фильтра неверно запрограммирована

Comment: @nick_n_a даже пусть инверсия, вопрос остается в силе - откуда рамка вокруг изображения...

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема с контуром "рамкой" изображения.  Вы смело берёте pixel[x',y'] не проверяя выходит ли x' y' за рамки изображения, а у вас выходит. Если бы у вас была бы проверка выхода за пределы массива - вы бы сразу получили исключение.

При выходе за границу нужно 1)брать тот цвет который был на границе (*у вас берётся что попало, и имеено поэтому у вас цвета на границе-кромке не просто неправильно считаются, а ещё и хаотично считаются, т.к. вы выходите за пределы отведённой памяти, закреплённой за вашими переменными, в с# или java уже было бы исключение*). 2) если нет, то написать алгоритм так что б эти точки не брались в расчёт 3) задать другие граничные условия

Для случая 1 - вам нужно вместо

```
pixel_value += weight[j + nHood/2][i + nHood/2] * temp[(y + j)*w + x + i];
```

учесть граничные координаты для temp, т.е

```
int x2,y2;
x2= x+j; y2=y+i;
if (x2 <0) x2=0;
if (y2 <0) y2=0;
if (x2 >=w) x2=w-1;
if (y2 >=h) y2=h-1;
pixel_value += weight[j + nHood/2][i + nHood/2] * temp[y2*w + x2];
```

это я учёл границу по temp. Ещё нужно вам учесть что б  weight не выходило за границу, скорее всего так:

```
int x2,y2,x3,y3;
x2= x+j; y2=y+i; // Новые  x y
if (x2 <0) x2=0; // Проверка границ
if (y2 <0) y2=0;
if (x2 >=w) x2=w-1;
if (y2 >=h) y2=h-1;
x3= j + nHood/2; // Новые  x y для веса
y3= i + nHood/2;
if (x3 <0) x3=0; // Проверка границ
if (y3 <0) y3=0;
if (x3 <=nHood) x3=nHood-1;
if (y3 <=nHood) y3=nHood-1;
pixel_value += weight[x3][y3] * temp[y2*w + x2];
```

Тогда изображение будет выглядеть более корректно.