# Ошибка в стеганографическом алгоритме Жао-Коха

Tags: ruby, стеганография

При встраивании сообщения в изображение все проходит без ошибок. Но считывание не происходит. Вдобавок на изображении со встроенным текстом появляется желтая полоса. Примеры кода и изображений прикрепляю.

```
def insert_message(image, text)
  dct = Array.new(8).map! { Array.new(8) }
  l = 0
  temp = Array.new(8).map! { Array.new(8) }
  (0..(image.columns - 1)).step(8) do |i|
    (0..(image.rows - 1)).step(8) do |j|
      break if l >= text.length * 8
      (0..7).each do |x|
        (0..7).each do |y|
          temp[x][y] = {
            :red => image.pixel_color(j + x, i + y).red,
            :green => image.pixel_color(j + x, i + y).green,
            :blue => image.pixel_color(j + x, i + y).blue
          }
        end
      end
      dct = dct(dct, temp)
      k = dct[3][4].abs - dct[4][3].abs
      if get_bit(text, l)
        if k <= 25
          dct[3][4] = (dct[3][4] >= 0) ? dct[4][3].abs + 150 : -1 * (dct[4][3].abs + 150)
        end
      else
        if k >= -25
          dct[4][3] = (dct[4][3] >= 0) ? dct[3][4].abs + 150 : -1 * (dct[3][4].abs + 150)
        end
      end

      temp = idct(dct, temp)
      (0..7).each do |x|
        (0..7).each do |y|
          pixel = Pixel.new(temp[x][y][:red], temp[x][y][:green], temp[x][y][:blue])
          image.pixel_color(j + x, i + y, pixel)
        end
      end
      l = l + 1
    end
    break if l >= text.length
  end
  image.write('cr.tiff')
  image
end
```

Функция встраивания сообщения

```
def read_message(image)
  out = []
  a = ''
  p = 0
  b = 0
  dct = Array.new(8).map! { Array.new(8) }
  temp = Array.new(8).map! { Array.new(8) }
  (0..(image.columns - 1)).step(8) do |i|
    (0..(image.rows - 1)).step(8) do |j|
      (0..7).each do |x|
        (0..7).each do |y|
          temp[x][y] = {
              red: image.pixel_color(j + x, i + y).red,
              green: image.pixel_color(j + x, i + y).green,
              blue: image.pixel_color(j + x, i + y).blue
          }
        end
      end
      dct = dct(dct, temp)

      k = dct[3][4].abs - dct[4][3].abs
      if k >= 25
        a = 1
      elsif k <= -25
        a = 0
      else
        a = -1
        break
      end
      b |= a << p
      if p == 7
        out.push(b.chr)
        b = 0
      end
      p = (p < 7) ? p + 1 : 0
    end

    if a == -1
      break
    end
  end
  out.join
end
```

Функция чтения из изображения

```
 def dct(dct, arr)
      (0..7).each do |i|
        (0..7).each do |j|
          temp = 0.0
          (0..7).each do |x|
            (0..7).each do |y|
              temp = temp + $cos_t[i][x] * $cos_t[j][y] * arr[x][y][:blue]
            end
          end
          dct[i][j] = $e[i][j] * temp
        end
      end
      dct
    end

def idct(dct, arr)
  (0..7).each do |i|
    (0..7).each do |j|
      temp = 0
      (0..7).each do |x|
        (0..7).each do |y|
          temp += dct[x][y] * $cos_t[x][i] * $cos_t[y][j] * $e[x][y]
          if temp > 255
            arr[i][j][:blue] = 255
          else
            if temp < 0
              arr[i][j][:blue] = 0
            else
              arr[i][j][:blue] = temp.round
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  arr
end
```

Функции ДКП и ОДКП

```
def get_bit(str,pos)
  return true if  str[pos/8].ord & (1 << pos % 8) > 0
  return false if  str[pos/8].ord & (1 << pos % 8) <= 0
end
```

Выбор бита

`$cos_t` `$e` - Константы.
Использую библиотеку `rmagick` и к нему модуль `Magick`
[image: Оригинал]
[image: Со встроенным текстом. Внимание на верхнюю часть]

Comment: Очень подозрительно выглядит работа с одним только `:blue` в ДКП и ОДКП. Жёлтая полоса наверняка связана с этим. И вообще странно, что в таких вроде бы обобщённых математических функциях идёт раскапывание цветов. Допускаю, что так могло быть сделано из соображений производительности, но что толку с этого, если алгоритм то ли поломался, то ли потерял скрытность результата.

Comment: Хотя это можно понять, если стеганография применяется только для синего канала.

Comment: @D-side Тут на самом деле странно реализован алгоритм, я посчитал, что если его выложили - значит рабочий. При общении с автором я спросил, про неиспользуемые переменные и этот момент с `:blue` Видимо поторопился. Успешнее будет самому реализовать видимо.. Математика все таки не сложная. Поставлю на конкурс параллельно.

Comment: Так как желтая полоса появилась вверху, то проверяйте граничные условия возле рамки. Что за значения берутся при выходе за пределы изображения. Думаю ответ на этот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674207/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-log-filter-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/674313#674313 вопрос к вашему так же касается. Проверьте условия возле границы изображения.

Comment: Интересная теория, но если ввести длинное слово для встраивания, то желтая полоса пойдет сверху вниз. Иными словами, если,  например, 100 раз  вставить букву "а" то картинка будет на 50% закрашена.

Comment: Примечательный факт: "жёлтая полоса" образована сбросом синей компоненты во всех (ну, или подавляюще многих) точках затронутой области до 1/255.

Comment: В функции чтения рубимайн пишет, что переменные dct и temp не инициализированы

Answer (score 0):

Можно придраться к стилю кода, но это не суть. Константы, правда, лучше большими буквами именовать -- тоже глобально (ну почти) видны станут, зато при правке ворнинг вылезет.

Я не знаю алгоритма, но проверь внимательно все индексы -- нигде ли оси не перепутаны. Здесь вижу в `temp` запись транспонируется:

```
      temp[x][y] = {
          red: image.pixel_color(j + x, i + y).red,
          green: image.pixel_color(j + x, i + y).green,
          blue: image.pixel_color(j + x, i + y).blue
      }
```

Хотя тут она транспонированно читается:

```
      pixel = Pixel.new(temp[x][y][:red], temp[x][y][:green], temp[x][y][:blue])
```

Ссылку в студию на код на другом языке, который был транслирован?

UPD: походу код отсюда https://habr.com/post/216207/
Какой ужас...

Comment: Да, код заимствован с хабра, но я его почистил от неиспользуемых переменных. Это одна из частей работы. в дальнейшем буду его улучшать. Проблема в том, что он не отрабатывает. К слову, рубимайн говорит, что в функции чтения переменные многие переменные не инициализированы.
сам код принадлежит Воробьеву Игнату - автору статьи, почту его светить не буду.
Пытался с ним связаться, но связь оборвалась.
На других языках примеры кода не видел. только функции ДКП и ОДКП на шарпе, которые следовали алгоритму в лоб.